# You dare to eat me?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Who am I?

> I lived a long successful life I did
>   Starting out was rough as a kid
>
> I seemed to catch break at age thirty eight
>   Working under the governor sure was great
>
> In '64 I dethroned a  king
>   Shortly after, a shipyard and naval academy became a thing
>
> My final moments were in '85
>   Nothing could be done about my demise
>
> Before I left a truce was signed
>   My legacy lives on for all of mankind

Will add hints if needed

Hint #1

> To be fair, the year thing may be very misleading and unfair.  So I will tell you not to get too hung up in the 20th century. For all I know denoting a year like '85 can only be referred to the 20th century. So I'll throw this early hint to everyone.

Hint #2

> I died at age 72

Hint #3 (Hopefully a good one!)

> I was a military leader in the Qing Dynasty

Comment: Are the apostrophes *after* the numbers significant? As in 64 feet rather than 1964?

Comment: They denote a year, not feet or anything else.

Comment: you'd put the apostrophes *before* the number then, i.e. '64 and '85. As with any other contraction, the apostrophe represents 'contracted' information, in this case, the "19" from each year.

Comment: @dperry Thanks, fixed it. I'm surprised I ever passed 6th grade most days.

Comment: A lot of things in your clues and hints point to this guy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Clinton,_1st_Earl_of_Lincoln

Comment: I think it may also have to do with the "Treaty of Vienna" which was signed in '64 (1864). && Vienna Sausages ;)

Comment: I updated my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

> Zuo Zongtang, or "[General Tso](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zuo_Zongtang)"
>
>
>  The dates match (1812-1885), he was hired as an advisor to Zeng Guofan (governor) in 1850, dethroned Hong Tianguifu in 1864, "founded China's first modern shipyard and naval academy in Fuzhou" in 1866. He died shortly after a truce was signed in the Sino-French war.

Comment: Can you put what you've got for Ulysses S Grant? Died in 1885, beat Robert E Lee (King of Spades?) in 1864, looks very promising to me.

Comment: There is also a famous ship called after Grant, captured from the Germans in 1917; the original name of the ship was "Konig Wilhelm II", that is "King William II". Ship + dethroned King, but the years do not match.

Comment: Nope, too many missing holes, good guess though!

Comment: You dare to eat "Ulysses S Grant"?

Comment: @albertrenshaw I addressed that *twice* in my answer

Comment: @question_asker My apologies O:)

Comment: Great Job! I figured that last clue would give it away. Haha.

Comment: Title referring to [General Tso's chicken](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Tso's_chicken)?

Comment: @f'' Exactly! I thought of this eating at a Chinese buffet. I figured it would be tricky until I gave some solid hints. Haha

Comment: I Love General Tso's Chicken, mmmm - fav. Chinese dish!

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to guess that you are the "House of York"

The title of the question is "You dare  to eat me" - York peppermint patties.

You said you died at age 72 and you died in the year '85, so you must have been born in '13. The house of York rose to power from 1413-1485 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Badges_of_England

The house of York had many kings in place so I'm sure something happened in '65 probably.

Also the House of York overthrew the previous "House of Lancaster", which is another food product company (Lancaster) hinting towards "you dare to eat me" once more.

Comment: I like this one, but don't see where the references to the governor, naval academy or shipyard fit in

Comment: Ah, I do like this answer.  But my third clue puts this in the wrong. ;) I also really like your Vienna Sausages comment on the OP. Haha

Answer (score 3):

I would guess the beatles.

1964 they ["dethroned" Elvis](http://www.elvis-history-blog.com/elvis-1964.html)

1985 their publishing rights were [bought up by Michael Jackson](http://www.history.com/this-day-in-history/michael-jackson-takes-control-of-the-beatles-publishing-rights)

But this is far-fetched and i can't fit the age 38 into this.

Comment: Nope! But those are some neat facts I didn't know about!

Comment: Also fits the title, "You dare to eat me", nice!